How can I use webhook in Messaging Services during trial mode?
I'm working on a WhatsApp chatbot and I've created a content template builder and messaging services. During the configuration of the messaging services, I selected "Send a webhook" and added my endpoint for the request URL.
Did I miss something, or does Twilio not allow any custom callbacks during sandbox mode?
When I try to interact with the template, Twilio uses the sandbox URL instead of the one I set up during integration.

I'm afraid this is the correct behavior. To use a messaging service, you would need to add the sandbox number to the sender pool of the service. However, this is not possible as you don't own the sandbox number.
You would need to upgrade the account and use your own number as a WhatsApp sender.
